# Changing title to lowercase

Tags: css, title

Lets say i have 100 posts. And i would like to lowercase the title. but only 70 of it. I cant use text-transform or mb_strtolower. Is there anyway to download posts and lowercase the title with microsoft word and reupload it?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: And why would you not ask how to do it in css/html rather than MS Word?

Comment: becouse i dont want to transform all posts, just half of it. when i add code to css it transforms all post. am i wrong?

Comment: Putting it in MS Word would and back would be more effort then just using quickedit or doing it in the browser.

Comment: Also titles should be using title case, not all lower or all upper case, what you want is bad english, and poor for readability

Comment: one of my user publishs all his posts uppercase (title) i want to edit them and make it normal.

Comment: there are more than 100 posts like that. i warn the user but now i have to edit the titles.

Comment: Well it's your publishers responsibility. Rather than teaching them its okay to mess up because you'll fix it, instead teach them that if they mess up they have to fix it so its best not to mess up at all

Comment: And if your a developer, you should teach clients that if they want you to do monkey work/repetitive work like that, it will cost them more than if they did it themselves. If it doesnt, then raise your rates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming this question is related to Wordpress, here is answer :- You can update the titles directly into your mySQL database using simple update function.

> one of my user publishs all his posts uppercase (title) i want to edit them and make it normal. –

Using some conditional statements as I mentioned in this code, you can restrict the update for particular user(replace 'user_id').

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_title=LOWER(post_title) WHERE post_author = "user_id"
```

This will transform all post titles into lowercase by that user.

Answer (score 1):

[**WP Title Case**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-title-case/) plugin would a much simpler solution. It automatically transforms titles across your website to show proper case.

> **For example:**
>
> "the quick brown fox" will appear as "The Quick Brown Fox"
>
> "i like wordpress so much" will appear as "I Like WordPress so Much"